# Strange behaviour of PolyLog Function

Tags: numerics, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

I discovered some strange behaviour of the `PolyLog[]` Function in *Mathematica* which seems to me like a bug in the function implementation.

It looks like `PolyLog` is breaking down for big arguments and non-integer orders

```
In[1]:=  -PolyLog[5/2, -E^500] // N
Out[1]:= 2.691151407447062*10^8626 + 9.87331945684138*10^8623 I
```

which is for sure incorrect. For such big arguments the `PolyLog` function has nice asymptotic approximations (which are e.g. used for complete Fermi-Dirac Integrals which are related to `PolyLog`'s) through $F_n(x)=-\mathrm{Li}_{n+1}(-e^x)$.

This can be demonstrated by using even orders for the `PolyLog[]` with similar big arguments

```
In[2]:=  -PolyLog[4, -E^500] // N
Out[2]:= 2.60437*10^9
```

if compared to the asymptotic approximation $\frac{u^n}{\Gamma(n+1)}$ of $-\mathrm{Li}_n(-e^u)$

```
In[3]:=  u^4/Gamma[5] /. u->500 //N
Out[3]:= 2.60417*10^9
```

the results look o.k.

The expected result of above given argument `E^500` and order `5/2` should be

```
In[4]:=  u^(5/2)/Gamma[5/2 + 1] /. u -> 500 // N
Out[4]:= 1.68209*10^6
```

I assume that the function algorithm somehow gets troubles with internal accuracy. Any ideas to "tell" *Mathematica* to increase the accuracy for the numerical calculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the following a better result?  (I'm not an expert.)

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100},
  N[-PolyLog[5/2, -E^500], 20]
]

(* Out: 1.6821298518320559359*10^6 + 0.*10^-14 I *)
```

Comment: Yes this is a better result - see update of question above. Thanks for the proposal. This leaves the question why Mathematica is not able to calculate the correct result in first place with the default accuracy.

Comment: @Rainer Again, I'm not an expert on PolyLogs specifically, but this is a common issue in special function evaluation.  I certainly wouldn't trust the result of `N[Sin[E^500]]`, I would be more comfortable with `N[Sin[E^500], 20]`, after increasing `$MaxExtraPrecision` to 400 or so.