# Why is PolyLog[] giving weird answers for ordinary values?

Tags: complex, special-functions

Possibly related to this question, but it seems slightly different:

[Strange behaviour of PolyLog Function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22341/strange-behaviour-of-polylog-function)

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Properties) that for real s, z<1 should be real. So I was confused when MMa returned:

```
PolyLog[0.5, -2.35]
-0.962331 + 1.96262*10^-17 I
```

Which, to be fair, has a teensy imaginary part. But still enough to mess up functions expecting only real values.

To get a better idea, I did

```
Plot[Im@PolyLog[.5, x], {x, -5, .5}]
```

Which gave me this plot:

[image]

So it seems to oscillate between 4 values for the imaginary part.

Can I just use Re[] to get rid of this part safely, i.e., is it just some artifact of the function? I don't need insane accuracy or anything, so as long as the real part is close to what it should be, it's alright.

Comment: Looks like floating point errors. Assuming `PolyLog` is working correctly and should ideally be real-valued, it should be safe to apply `Re`, if a purely real output is desired.

Comment: Try: `Plot[PolyLog[1/2, x], {x, -5, 5}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`

Comment: Proposed duplicates: [(3152)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3152/121), [(71675)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71675/121)